# How to write a program that asks the user to enter a number between 0 and 1000, inclusive....continued

Tags: python, format, turtle-graphics

Question: **Write a program that asks the user to enter a number between 0 and 1000, inclusive (that is, including the end points 0 and 1000). If they enter a number out of range, print a message that the number is out of range and prompt them again for a number between 0 and 1000, inclusive. When the user enters a number in range, print the number to the screen and end the program.**

I have written the program, but I am **NOT** sure I am using the `while` statement correctly. Please check my program and give feed backs.
**My problem: If I enter a negative number twice, it is not asking for a number third time. Please help!!**

Here is my program:

```
from turtle import*
def ask():
    m = eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1000, inclusive: "))
    return m

def inclusive(i):
    i = -1
    while i < 0 or i > 1000:
        print("Out of range, my boy. Try again!")
        i = ask()

    return i


def main():
    n = ask()
    m = inclusive(m)  
    win = Screen()
    win.bgcolor("black")
    ahamed = Turtle()
    ahamed.pencolor("blue")
    ahamed.write(m,font=["Arial",90])
    ahamed.hideturtle()

    exitonclick()

main()
```

My problem: If I enter negative number twice, it is not asking for the number third time. Please help!!

Comment: Do __NOT__ use `eval(input(...)`, use `int(input(...))`

Comment: I am entering a number, not a string

Comment: Yes I know, it is better practice to use int or input instead of eval

Comment: Wrong - you are actually entering a string. If you use `eval` to turn the entered string into an integer, the user can execute code, like `exit()` to exit the program, or other possibly dangerous stuff. `int()` just tries to turn it into an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your while condition to as follows:

```
def ask():
    return int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1000, inclusive: "))

def inclusive():
    i = -1
    while i < 0 or i > 1000:
        print("Out of range, my boy. Try again!")
        i = ask()
    return i

def main():
    m = inclusive()
    print(m)
```

Comment: Try entering `-1`, `-1`, `5`. You will realize the problem. @sshashank124

Comment: Now the problem is it is not printing the number to the screen.

Comment: @socrates, You need to assign output of inclusive to a variable

Comment: Just a little help, I will do it myself.

Comment: @socrates, The way I am doing it in my main function. Try out the demo I linked in the comments

Comment: @socrates, Please note __ALL__ the changes I made to my code. See that inclusive no longer takes an argument and there is no ask() before inclusive in main

Comment: The problem is if I enter `4` and it is asking for a number again

Comment: @socrates, Did you try my demo. I cannot help you if you refuse to look at _ALL_ the changes in my code

Comment: @socrates, Glad to be of help